# GRE logic problem

Tags: logic

So I am confused on the negation of the following:

Let $f,g$ be continuous on the reals.

Negate the statement:

For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that if $f(x)>0$, then $g(y)>0$.

So the answer is

there exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$  $f(x)>0$ and $g(y) \leq 0$.

Could someone explain this a bit more, that isn't the choice I selected and I am bothered I couldn't get the logic right here. Gotta be careful with quantifiers.

Comment: You want "There is an x∈R such that, **for all y**, f(x)>0 and g(y)≤0.

Comment: The answer you've given can't be right, because $y$ isn't quantified over.

Comment: editing now sorry, I forgot I left that out, a pretty key step lol.

Comment: @user247327 yeah sorry lol

Comment: Break it down piece by piece. "For each $x$, there exists $y$ such that" (every $x$ has a $y$ match such that...) negated would be that "for some $x$ there does not exist a $y$ such that if $f(x) > 0$, then $g(y)>0$". Equivalently since there is no $y$ that makes $g(y)$ positive when $f(x)$ is positive, you can say that "there exists an $x$ such that for all $y$, $f(x) > 0$ and $g(y) \le 0$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My own attempt is as follows:

Let the given statement be

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists y \in \mathbb{R} \text{s.t.}$$

$$f(x) > 0 \Rightarrow g(y)>0.$$

Then negating becomes

$$\exists x \in \mathbb{R} \text{s.t.} \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$$

$$f(x) >0 \wedge g(y) \leq 0.$$

as needed.

Answer (score 1):

$\neg$ for all = there exists.

$\neg$ there exists = for all.

Saying “if p then q” is the same as “$p \implies q.$”

The negation of $p \implies q$ is [$p$ and $\neg q$].

So $\neg(f(x) > 0 \implies g(y) > 0)$ is [$f(x) > 0$ and $g(y) \leq 0$]